# Unicode string to Chinese characters

Tags: c#, unicode, character-encoding, arrays, cjk

I have a unicode string, let's say "U+660E", and I want to display the corresponding character, which in this case is 明. See [this page](http://smontagu.damowmow.com/genEncodingTest.cgi?family=windows&codepage=950)  (ctrl-F to find 明).

My code so far:

```
string unicodeString = reader.GetString(0);
unicodeString.Trim();

Encoding codepage = Encoding.GetEncoding(950);
Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
byte[] encodedBytes = codepage.GetBytes(unicodeString);
//unicodeString = Encoding.Convert(codepage, unicode, encodedBytes).ToString();
unicodeString = unicode.GetString(encodedBytes);
richTextBox1.Text = unicodeString;
```

My output is "⭕㘶䔰�".
Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: `reader.GetString(0)` should have returned the correct string.

Comment: Nop.. after commenting out everything except the reader.GetString(0) I get the exact string back "U+660E", which is to be expected right? DOn't I need to tell the DB to 'convert'. Because the DB will treat it as a literal string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.net deals directly with unicode.  You do **not** have to play the encoding games.  Just tell the reader if the input is UTF-8 or UTF-16 and then deal with it as a normal string.

```
richTextBox1.Text = reader.GetString(0)
```

Comment: Does it matter if the reader is SQLDatareader? The code is wrapped in: using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    }
                }
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

Comment: SQL data reader handles unicode.  Just make sure that the column is declared for unicode text (nvarchar, nchar, etc)

Comment: Thank you! I think I can handle it from here. You are 明 (brilliant) lol.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to convert to CP-950; C# is Unicode through-and-through. Just input and print as Unicode unless you're outputting to a file that you know has to be CP-950.